# Custom ScrollEventHandler not returning NewValue upon scrolling

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here.  I basically created my own scrolleventhandler within a custom listview so that I could get more control.  The OnScroll function gets called but for whatever reason NewValue is always 0 and OldValue is always -1.  Any reason why it's not being updated correctly?

```
public class ListViewXP : System.Windows.Forms.ListView
{        
 ...        
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

    private const int SB_HORZ = 0;
    private const int SB_VERT = 1;

    public delegate void ScrollEventHandler(Object sender, ScrollEventArgs e);
    public event ScrollEventHandler Scroll;

    protected virtual void OnScroll(ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollEventHandler handler = this.Scroll;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
        {
            int scrollPos = 0;

            if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL)
                scrollPos = GetScrollPos(this.Handle, SB_HORZ);
            else
                scrollPos = GetScrollPos(this.Handle, SB_VERT);

            OnScroll(new ScrollEventArgs((ScrollEventType)(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff), scrollPos));
        }
    }

    ..
}


    listView1.Scroll += new ListViewXP.ScrollEventHandler(listView1_OnScroll);

    private void listView1_OnScroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.NewValue.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.OldValue.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: You are using the wrong constructor.  And you always pass 0 for *newvalue*.  Have a peek at the way the [framework does it](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/ScrollableControl.cs,1456).  Do keep in mind that the omission of the ListView.Scroll event was intentional, the values you get are not correlated to the list.

Answer (score 0):

Within WndProc you are creating the ScrollEventArgs object that ultimately gets used in listView1_OnScroll. You're setting NewValue to 0, and not setting OldValue at all.

Try something like this:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL || m.Msg == WM_VSCROLL)
    {
        int scrollPos = 0;
        if (m.Msg == WM_HSCROLL)
          scrollPos = GetScrollPos(this.Handle, SB_HORZ);
        else
          scrollPos = GetScrollPos(this.Handle, SB_VERT);

        OnScroll(new ScrollEventArgs((ScrollEventType)(m.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff), scrollPos));
    }
}
```

If you want to set OldValue as well you'll need to store NewValue as a member variable and use the overloaded constructor for ScrollEventArgs.

Comment: Hi Wheatin, so I updated my original post and made the changes as you suggested. However, my scrollPos is still coming back as 0 all the time.